pubsub client You have passed an invalid argument to the service (argument={{projectId}})
I am trying to implement this retry logic + send messages by batch
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-retry-settings#pubsub_publisher_retry_settings-nodejs_typescript
But I see an error on the client.publish call. You have passed an invalid argument to the service (argument={{projectId}})
export const instance = new PubSub()
export const pubSubClient = new v1.PublisherClient();

export const psaWorkerTopic = instance.topic(
  MAIN.PSA_WORKER_PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME,
  { messageOrdering: true }
)

const request = {
  topic: psaWorkerTopic.name,
  messages: messages.map((message) => ({
    data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message.data)),
    orderingKey: message.orderingKey,
  })),
};

const [response] = await pubSubClient.publish(request, CLIENT_PUBLISH_OPTIONS);

But at the same time  psaWorkerTopic.publishMessage(message) works without any problems.
What is wrong and why PublisherClient is not parsing projctId from env?
